# How to represent touch gestures in interactive prototypes for Multi-touch apps (Android / IOS)

Tags: interaction-design, touch-screen, prototype

I have always wondered that, How can we represent/show multi-touch gestures like swipe, pinch etc in mockups / interactive prototypes.

For example, I'm currently prototyping in Axure for an Android app. I have a function like shown in the image. Or probably like (Long Press, move, lift) to delete/move icons in Android.

User can interact through it and **tap can be represented by Onclick in Axure**, but how can I tell effectively that a particular gesture on a particular item on screen will do something.

So, I just want to know how can we represent these gestures in both static and interactive prototypes (like in Axure).

[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to make Axure recognize multi-touch gestures in live prototypes? Or are you asking how to indicate gestures in static wireframes?

Comment: Actually my question was both for static and interactive prototypes. I mentioned Axure cos i'm using it.

Comment: [A quick overview of 8 icon sets](http://thedesigninspiration.com/articles/8-gesture-icon-sets-for-designing-multi-touch-interfaces/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This **open source library** is pretty good to start with and covers many types of common gestures:
http://gestureworks.com/downloads/icons-poster.zip

[image: Gestureworks]

---

Alternatively, this one is pretty good as well:
http://gesturecons.com

[image: Gesturecons]

---

You could also try a **short video** or **animated GIF** images to make the gestures more explicit, [VideoHive offers many footages](http://videohive.net/search?ref=wildpeaks&utf8=%E2%9C%93&term=gestures) you could use to that effect.

Comment: `HTTP 404`: The icons poster is [here](http://gestureworks.com/downloads/icons-poster.zip). 190MB as for today .

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a fan of Axure for this reason. It's interactive, but not interactive in the way the final product is, so can't possibly communicate the actual interaction and, typically, will only confuse in the interim.

For static mockups, Luke Wroblewski has a nice set of gesture notation:

http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1071

Comment: So which other prototyping app would you recommend instead of Axure. Is there any other?

Comment: By default, the only web prototyping app I recommend is HTML/CSS and JS. I argue it's as difficult to figure out as Axure is, but is actually pertinent to what you are building, while Axure prototypes really only make sense in the context of Axure.